# Missing dependency for method when doing a file upload rest web service

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I've been trying to understand how to fix this error:

```
SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public java.lang.String com.myrest.FileService.uploadFile(java.io.File,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition) at parameter at index 0
SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public java.lang.String com.myrest.FileService.uploadFile(java.io.File,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition) at parameter at index 1
SEVERE: Method, public java.lang.String com.myrest.FileService.uploadFile(java.io.File,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition), annotated with POST of resource, class com.myrest.FileService, is not recognized as valid resource method.
```

I am working with a Apache Jersey based rest web service and doing a upload service.

Anyone have encountered this error before?

I am getting this error for this code:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/upload{path:.*}")
    @Consumes("multipart/form-data")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String uploadFile(
            @FormDataParam("file") File file, 
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

        String fileLocation = "/files/" + fileDetail.getFileName();
        System.out.println("Copying file to : " + fileLocation);
        return "1";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line of the error message makes me think you have a missing JAR file.

```
class com.myrest.FileService, is not recognized as valid resource method.
```

But other than that I have not seen @FormDataParam being bound to a java.io.File before, not sure if the framework can deserialize it to that object. Have you tried deserializing to a java.io.InputStream instead? Also, if you are using Maven to build then check your POM for all required dependencies.

Answer (score 22):

In my case the problem were different library versions of `jersey-bundle` and `com.sun.jersey.contribs`; after settign both to the same version everything worked.

Comment: Same here, I had a wrong version of the multipart. thanks a lot!!