# Cannot implement simple file upload in Jersey - "annotated with POST of resource, class is not recognized as valid resource method. unavailable"

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Unable to implement simple file upload using Jersey.  Missing dependency errors raised at application bootstrap:

```
The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.foo.MyResource.uploadFile(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition) at parameter at index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.foo.MyResource.uploadFile(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition) at parameter at index 1
  SEVERE: Method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.foo.uploadFile(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition), annotated with POST of resource, class com.foo.FS2Resource, is not recognized as valid resource method.
unavailable
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
```

It seems like there is an issue with mapping the input parameters to a REST service?  I have read documentation and followed several examples, and I am not deviating from those examples.

Here's the code:

```
@Path("v1/")
public class FileUploadResource {


    @POST
    @Path("upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream is,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition detail) {

        String name = detail.getFileName();

        // do upload stuff
        String output = .... 

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }

}
```

I pulled in "compile 'com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-multipart:1.17.1'" for the FormDataParams.

**EDIT**: I was able to get it working in Jersey but only in this more primitive fashion:

```
 @POST
 @Path("upload")
 @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)     
 @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)

 public Response uploadFile(final MimeMultipart file) {
   if (file == null) {
     return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("Must supply a valid file").build();

   try {
     for (int i = 0; i < file.getCount(); i++) {
       // ... do something with file.getBodyPart(i));
     }
     return Response.ok("done").build();
   } catch (final Exception e) {
     return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(e).build();
   }
 }
```

This is probably a sufficient workaround, but would still like to get to the bottom of the issue.

Comment: I'm actually running into a similar problem. I have the same corresponding version of the all required jersey jars, and each of my FormDataParam values are different to avoid the future mapping problem. However, I still have the bootstrap issue as well. Is there a problem with using the Post and Produces annotations together or something? The only method I've have this trouble with is my Post one.

Comment: It was mentioned to me by a colleague that this is a known bug and that the reason it works for some is that it has to do with the specific distribution/configuration that you are working with.

Comment: A bug on what, exactly? The FormDataParam annotation or Jersey?

Comment: Same and same solution, thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem.

It was a version problem (I'd 1.8 in jersey.multipart and 1.17.1 in the rest of jersey). Setting all of them to 1.17.1 workrd for mee.

Took my answer from here:

[Missing dependency for method when doing a file upload rest web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658699/missing-dependency-for-method-when-doing-a-file-upload-rest-web-service)

Comment: Perfecto bro...great answer, worked like a bullet, this is the same issue with me, have used 1.8 and 1.17.1 both, great (clap)

Answer (score 1):

One visible problem in your code is that, you are using the same name for both the input multipart param i.e. "file"

```
@FormDataParam("file")
```

Multipart params do have an identifier, so you need to use the correct name for the second object in your method signature. Otherwise same param is going in `inputstream` and also for `FormDataContentDisposition`.

Comment: That makes some sense, but this is a bootstrap issue and not runtime.  Also, the JavaDoc for FormDataParam actually suggests using "file" in both cases.

Comment: @rob the doc you are following is wrong. Two multipart param having the same name cannot be mapped properly. Try changing the name of form params in the client and use the same name in your method.

Comment: I changed the names to humor you and still see the same issue.  Remember, this is bootstrap... client has nothing to do with this issue.  It's happening at the *startup* of the container.  I would be happy to be dealing with mapping issues at this point, but unfortunately I am not even there yet. :)

Comment: «this is a bootstrap issue and not runtime» Wrong: Jersey bootstrap is runtime, not compile time. However I'm getting the same issue at bootstrap, and I have different name for every part, I'm also using the same version but still having the same issue, any idea?

Comment: Obviously I'm talking about using @FormDataParam