# I got a com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I wrote a method to upload a file by jersey like this:

```
@POST
@Path("file")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream in,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDisposition,
        @FormDataParam("fileName") String fileName){
    String fullName = fileDisposition.getFileName();
    try {
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(
                new File("D://",
                fileName + fullName.substring(fullName.indexOf('.'))));
        int index = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
        while( (index = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
            os.write(buffer , 0 , index);
        }
        in.close();
        os.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    return fullName;
}
```

As you see,it is so easy.But when I deploy it to Tomcat,I got a error:

```
  严重: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public java.lang.String rest.upload.Upload.uploadFile(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition,java.lang.String) at parameter at index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public java.lang.String rest.upload.Upload.uploadFile(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition,java.lang.String) at parameter at index 1
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public java.lang.String rest.upload.Upload.uploadFile(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition,java.lang.String) at parameter at index 2
  SEVERE: Method, public java.lang.String rest.upload.Upload.uploadFile(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition,java.lang.String), annotated with POST of resource, class rest.upload.Upload, is not recognized as valid resource method.
八月 29, 2014 6:01:30 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
严重: StandardWrapper.Throwable
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException

八月 29, 2014 6:01:30 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
严重: Servlet /upload threw load() exception
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
```

Ok,what i can do to solve the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot implement simple file upload in Jersey - "annotated with POST of resource, class is not recognized as valid resource method. unavailable"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431012/cannot-implement-simple-file-upload-in-jersey-annotated-with-post-of-resource)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I known later,the annotation @FormDataParam used jar named jersey_multipart.jar and its path is
com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataParam.

what is more, it doennot the same as other annotations such as @POST/@PathParam which path is  javax.ws.rs.*;

And this problem is that when I add jersey_multipart.jar into the project,its version is 1.18 and the jersey-core.jar is version 1.14.So they have conflict with each other.

So I let these jars version the same, and the problem solved by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, In your runtime classpath, you have added 
1) jersey-multipart-1.17.1.jar
2) mimepull-1.6.jar

Apart from this, you should have same version as jersey-core or jersey-bundle.